# Want to make a background png with a bootstrap navbar, but it won't work

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

I want to make a background image for a navbar. At this point, its looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYZrt.png).

The navbar is scrolling with the site, but it's very dark at times so you don't see it very well. So I wanted to add a background for that, but that don't work either. Here's my code that I'm using...

```css
.nav {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-image: url("img/navbar_background");
  /* (that wont work) */
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <img src="img/marco_d_word_logo.svg" class="logo-image nav-link">
  <a class="nav-link" href=".ueber_mich">Über mich</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Meine Arbeit</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Impressum</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is your filepath ok? Do you see the image being requested in the sources panel of the dev tools? Add .png to the path

Comment: You are missing the extension for the image.

Comment: What extension do I need?

Comment: Yeah, I see it being requested

Answer (score 0):

don't fotget to write the extension of the image:

```
.nav{
   background: url("img/navbar_background.png") no-repeat;
   background-size: 100% 100%; // to fit the image to the nav
}
```